# Compiler agnostic fortran name mangling function

Tags: c++, fortran, name-mangling

I am dynamically linking to a fortran static object and need to be able (at run time) to take the name of the fortran function (which is a C++ string) and name mangle it appropriately for the compiler. Is there any pre-built function that would serve this purpose? In the statically linked case I am using autoconf's FC_FUNC.

For clarity, I want a function that would be able to take a string, interpret it as a fortran subroutine name and mangle it appropriately for the given compiler. In psuedo-C++,:

```
std::string subroutine = "FORTRANSUBROUTINE";
std::string symbol     = FortranMangle(subroutine);

std::cout << symbol << endl; // Would output something like "fortransubroutine_"
```

I do not know all of the used name mangling schemes to write this mysterious "FortranMangle" function, myself.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this (never done anything alike so I'm curious?

Comment: @Rook probably because he wants to access fortran routines in runtime with dlopen, but since the symbol changes according to the fortran compiler, he does not know what to pass to dlsym

Comment: @Stefano - Ah, ok. But, how many compilers is he using that he cannot do this by hand?

Comment: I can do this by hand. However, if something exists that is far more robust than what I write then I'd rather use it. What's more, I'm not in a development environment where I've got access to a large array of compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty C solution that abuses the existing macros to extract the mangling rules and print the mangled result. Most of this gets elided by the optimizer, so only the relevant cases exist. You should be able to adapt this to your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* The autoconf macros, predefined here for uppercase, underscore,
 * extra underscore */
#define FC_FUNC(name, NAME) NAME ## _
#define FC_FUNC_(name, NAME) NAME ## __

#define STR(arg) STR1(arg)
#define STR1(arg) #arg

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char normal[] = STR(FC_FUNC(l, U));
    const char w_uscore[] = STR(FC_FUNC_(l, U));
    char ucase, uscore, extra_uscore;
    char buf[256];
    int i;

    ucase = normal[0] == 'l' ? 0 : 1;
    if (sizeof(normal) > sizeof("l"))
        uscore = 1;
    else
        uscore = 0;

    if (sizeof(w_uscore) > sizeof(normal))
        extra_uscore = 1;
    else
        extra_uscore = 0;

    printf("upper: %d uscore: %d extra :%d\n", ucase, uscore, extra_uscore);

    if (argc < 2)
        return -1;

    /* Copy string, converting case */
    for (i=0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        buf[i] = ucase ? toupper(argv[1][i]) : tolower(argv[1][i]);
    }

    if (uscore)
        buf[i++] = '_';

    if (extra_uscore && strchr(argv[1], '_'))
    {
        buf[i++] = '_';
    }

    buf[i] = '\0';

    printf("old: %s - new %s\n", argv[1], buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Frankly, that's *very* clever and I like it.
As far as I can see it covers all the possible name manglings given in the Wiki article on name mangling - I suppose to your knowledge there are no more? Oh, and whilst the compiler optimisation will get rid of most of this code - will it do the same if I adapt it to use C++ strings?

Comment: My knowledge is based only on the code generating the macros in the current version of Autoconf. it should support all manglings supported by same.

Comment: @VolatileStorm: I'd keep `normal` and `w_uscore` as plain C strings. They're only used to detect the mangling requirements. C++ strings might not get optimized away.

Comment: Ah well it doesn't matter too much as any calls to the mangling function are only done once at run time, so I'd rather maintain readability than grab at a little bit of (unnecessary) speed.
Not to say that C is unreadable, just as someone more familiar with C++ I found it hard to read as, for example, I'm not used to "buffer" syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to access fortran routines in runtime from C with dlopen. Since the symbol changes according to the fortran compiler, you don't  know what to pass to dlsym in order to get the symbol.

one possible solution is to specify the fortran routine you want to call with [BIND(C)](http://www.fortran.bcs.org/2002/interop.htm). This removes name mangling and uses C-style symbol name, that is, one-to-one mapping.

The alternative is that you know how the mangling is done, and implement the FortranMangle routine accordingly. There's nothing premade for that, because mangling is compiler specific and there's nothing in the spec about this.

Comment: ISO_C_BINDING isn't available on some target platforms, unfortunately! And I know that there's nothing in the fortran spec about name mangling, but is there anywhere that has a concise list of manglings?(If it comes to that). There are probably compilers out there that are going to be used that I wouldn't think of.

Comment: As suggested, the Fortran "ISO C Binding" method will remove the compiler dependence.    "Subroutine FortXYZ (args) bind (C, name="realname")" will appear to the linker as "realname" without any mangling.

Comment: What platform doesn't have a Fortran compiler that supports the ISO C Binding?  gfortran has supported it since version 4.3.1, which was released over three years ago.

Comment: The ISO_C_BINDING module isn't present on a few target platforms - we only recently got them to upgrade from g77!
Further information - older versions of Scientific Linux are running GCC 4.1.3.

Comment: Absolutely no experience with Fortran, but one basically has the same problem in C++ and the crossplatform solution (apart from extern "C") is to use a .def file which exports the function unmangled. According to [this](http://afome.com/fortrandll.php) that should work in Fortran as well.